# How to fix bluetooth sound quality issue after Mojave update?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth, mojave

After updating to Mojave my bluetooth headset sounds terrible and muffled. After testing several bluetooth devices I was able to diagnose it wasn't the hardware. After researching I found:

- [BT Sounds bad on Mojave](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8555097)
- Bluetooth Quality Issue since Mojave Update

but after testing the above it didn't resolve the issue and searching on the site with the queries:

- [mojave terrible](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmojave%5D%20terrible)
- [mojave audio](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mojave+audio)

I didn't see this asked. Is there a way to repair or correct the sound issue with bluetooth devices in Mojave?

Comment: You've linked several searches, but I'm not sure what you're trying to point out as an example.  It's better if you used *specific* examples rather than broad searches.

Comment: Also, if an update breaks something (in this case Bluetooth), the only two fixes are to a) wait for a fix from Apple or b) roll back your update.  The latter is usually done via Time Machine or APFS snapshots; but the caveat is, you have to do the backup/snapshot first.

Comment: However, it might be beneficial to see if a snapshot is available - issue the command `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /`.  If one exists prior to your update, you may be in luck.